# values are seen in firebug but array length is shown as undefined

Tags: javascript

see below the code used from my end.

```
var len1=document.getElementById(div_name);
            alert(len1.length);
```

Values are getting populated for len1 array in firebug. but when i try to get the length of len1.length i get it as undefined.

share me your suggestions
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A document element is not an array. The thing you're looking at in Firebug is an object.

Unlike jQuery's `$()` method, `getElementById()` will return either a single object, or `null` if no match was found.

If you want to know if you matched anything:

```
var len1 = document.getElementById(div_name);    

if (len1 === null)
{
  alert('oops');
}
```

Comment: one match was found... i see values populated but length function shows as undefined :(

Comment: Because it's not an array, nor is it a string, or anything else with a meaningful length. There is no `length` function. Why would there be?

Answer (score 0):

Why you've decided that `document.getElementById` returns array with length property? It doesn't return any array, it returns [`element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element) that doesn't have this property. That's why you have `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById()` returns a single DOM element, not an array, and that element does not have the `length` property (this is why you see `undefined`). If you're trying to get multiple elements with that ID, then this is a wrong approach, as in valid code there can exist only one element with a given ID (and there is no `getElementsById()`).